# docker: invalid reference format. run Discord bot using DOCKER on Synology NAS

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to run Discord bot using DOCKER on Synology NAS, but I get an error like the title.
The corresponding command is docker run -v /volume1/docker/python:/app \ -it python:3.8.6 bash -c 'pip3 install discord && python /app/bot.py'

reboot or  reinstall